# PHP - Converter string em int

Tags: php

Estou tentando converter a `string` '450.000,00' em `int` para inserir no banco de dados. Porém quando faço `cast` ou uso `intval()`, o valor retornado vai para 450 apenas. No caso eu preciso do 450.000.

Qual outra forma poderia fazer isso?

Comment: amo php por isso number_format($numero, '2', '', ''); testa ai

Comment: Primeiro você precisa remover os pontos, em seguida trocar vírgula por ponto, e só então converter.

Answer (score -5):

Sem delongas a solução mais porca e útil:

```
$number = "450.000,00";
$numbers = explode(',', $number);
$numberss = explode('.', $numbers[0]);
$string = $numberss[0].$numberss[1].$numbers[1];
```

Comment: Votei -1 porque a solução é realmente ruim. Faz `explode` de forma desnecessária e basicamente só funciona para o exemplo apresentado na pergunta. Se a entrada fosse `"450000,00"` ou `"1.450.000,00"` não iria mais funcionar.

Comment: "Porca" eu não classificaria, mas é inútil.

Comment: haha, deixa ai a questão é duplicada achei um monte de solução!